# Why is the type inference to a BiConsumer for a one-argument instance method different in this case?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, type-inference, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to compile this piece of code:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ModelService;

public class Foo {

    public static interface ModelService2 {
        public abstract void saveAll(Object[] paramArrayOfObject) throws ModelSavingException;
        public abstract void saveAll(Collection<? extends Object> paramCollection) throws ModelSavingException;
        public abstract void saveAll() throws ModelSavingException;
    }

    public void bar() {
        final BiConsumer<ModelService2, Collection<? extends Object>> consumer1 = ModelService2::saveAll;
        final BiConsumer<ModelService, Collection<? extends Object>> consumer2 = ModelService::saveAll;
    }
}
```

The interface [`ModelService`](https://download.hybris.com/api/5.7.0/commercesuite/de/hybris/platform/servicelayer/model/ModelService.html)  is defined by the SAP hybris platform. `ModelService2` just replicates the overloaded methods with name `saveAll` defined in the interface of the hybris platform.

I get the following compiler error when compiling the above:

```
1. ERROR in src\Foo.java (at line 17)
    final BiConsumer<ModelService, Collection<? extends Object>> consumer2 = ModelService::saveAll;
                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method saveAll(Object[]) from the type ModelService
```

Why does the compiler do different type inference for `ModelService` when the only difference I'm able to spot is where each of the interfaces is located?

I'm using javac 1.8.0_77 for compilation in this case. Eclipse for example doesn't report any errors for the above code.

**EDIT:**

A relatively similiar error happens also for the following variable declarations:

```
final Consumer<ModelService2> consumer3 = ModelService2::saveAll;
final Consumer<ModelService> consumer4 = ModelService::saveAll;
```

The compile error in this case is:

```
1. ERROR in src\Foo.java (at line 19)
    final Consumer<ModelService> consumer4 = ModelService::saveAll;
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method saveAll(Object[]) from the type ModelService
```

**EDIT2:**

compilation arguments are:

```
'-noExit'
'-classpath'
'<classpath>'
'-sourcepath'
'<source path>'
'-d'
'<path>\classes'
'-encoding'
'UTF8'
```

**EDIT 3:**
These are the definitions for the 3 methods shown by the Eclipse class file viewer:

```
  // Method descriptor #43 (Ljava/util/Collection;)V
  // Signature: (Ljava/util/Collection<+Ljava/lang/Object;>;)V
  public abstract void saveAll(java.util.Collection arg0) throws de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException;

  // Method descriptor #45 ([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  public abstract void saveAll(java.lang.Object... arg0) throws de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException;

  // Method descriptor #10 ()V
  public abstract void saveAll() throws de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException;
```

**Resolution:**

The problem is caused by the eclipse compiler for java v4.4.1. It is fixed since at least v4.5.1. I failed to notic that it was the eclipse compiler that was used by the hybris platform to compile the code when building from the command line at first.

Comment: Is the `saveAll` method in `ModelService2` a `static` method? See "Kinds of Method References" on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Is ModelService generic by any chance? Without see the code of the class you can't use, I would be just guessing.

Comment: @Marco13 From the documentation you posted I want a `Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type` taking one argument

Comment: @PeterLawrey The interface `ModelService` has no type parameters. It has some other methods with type parameters, but all overloads of `saveAll` do not have type parameters.

Comment: Can you make sure that the overloads of saveAll in ModelService all return void? Usually with different return types or different parameter types, the compiler comes up with this strange : "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method" error.

Comment: @user3493289 Yes, all of these methods return void. See the javadoc of the `ModelService`: https://download.hybris.com/api/5.7.0/commercesuite/de/hybris/platform/servicelayer/model/ModelService.html

Comment: Compiled successfully with `jdk1.8.0_60` and `jdk1.8.0_65`. Will check u77 soon…

Comment: @Holger against which hybris platform version did you compile? I'm using 5.7.0.2

Comment: I don't have the Hybris library locally so I created a dummy `ModelService`, with three `saveAll` with the same signatures as the real ones. In this setting all of your examples compile for me, both with Eclipse 4.5.2 and javac 1.8.0_77.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: What happens if you change the `ModelService2.saveAll(Object[] os)` to be a vararg method? `ModelService2.saveAll(Object... os)`?

Comment: @Lii That's the cause of the problem. It will then report the same errors as for the original `ModelService`.

Comment: @Stretch because I need to pass a method reference of `ModelService::saveAll` to a method. That method will do the work required for Mockitos `ArgumentCaptor`. Therefore I'm able to use the ArgumentCaptor as a one-liner.

Comment: So not trying to achieve anything worthwhile then. GL HF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interaction between method overloading, varargs and type inference is perhaps the most complicated and hairy part of Java type checking. It's an area where bugs turn up regularly and where there are often differences between different compilers.

My guess is the following:

`ModelService` has a vararg `saveAll`. Because of this `saveAll` with two object argument is a valid method call to such an object. If that method would be static it would be valid to call it with one `ModelService` and one `Collection`, so a method reference expression would be valid for a `BiConsumer<ModelService2, Collection<? extends Object>>` type.

Because of a compiler bug the compiler notes that, and notes that the method in not static, and thus infers that the method reference expression is not valid here. This generates the compilation error.

`ModelService2.saveAll` is on the other hand is not a vararg and can not be called with one `ModelService` and one `Collection`. Because of this the compiler does not get stuck in this bug when it tries that possibility.

When I tried this code with Eclipse 4.5.2 and javac 1.8.0_77 all of your examples compiled for me. I have no idea why you are getting different results.

Comment: So varargs may induce such a bug but none of `jdk1.8.0_05`, `jdk1.8.0_20`, `jdk1.8.0_40`, `jdk1.8.0_51`, `jdk1.8.0_60`, `jdk1.8.0_65` nor `jdk1.8.0_77` reproduces the problem…

Comment: @Holger: Could it be that @SpaceTrucker compiles against the class file of `ModelService`, which might be compiled with some other compiler, and that this makes a difference?

Comment: according to the OP, changing the array parameter in the nested interface `ModelService2` to a varargs method materializes the problem as well (wasn’t it you who asked about that?). For the nested class, we can safely assume that it gets compiled using the same compiler.

Comment: @Holger I'm still trying to find out how exactly the build process and compilation work exactly in the hybris platform. The `ModelService.class` I'm compiling against comes with the hybris platform. Eclipse class file viewer tells me `// Compiled from ModelService.java (version 1.8 : 52.0, no super bit)`

Comment: @Holger The problem is I'm also unable to reproduce this when only using compiling in a plain java project only containing `ModelService2` and not using any build tools and process of the hybris platform. So I think the hybris platform has some configuration that causes this error to happen.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: the big question is indeed, what compiler is used in your build process. As I named quite some older JDK versions not having this problem, it’s more likely either, a custom compiler or ECJ (the Eclipse compiler) of an older version, is embedded in the build tools. I wouldn’t be surprised finding such a bug in older ECJ versions…

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: In the class file viewer in Eclipse of the Hybris class file, what are the types of the  `saveAll` methods? For example, is it `Object[]` or `Object...`? (Better add that to the question instead of as a comment.)

Comment: @Holger This seems to be a bug of the eclipse compiler for java version 4.4.1, because after a lot of searching I found out that we used this in our project instead of javac. Since I don't have this bug in eclipse with ecj 4.5.1 it seems to have been fixed.